# cannot find symbol, symbol: variable DBHandler location: class ProcessBean

Tags: java, servlets

I have two classes in package helpers, ProcessBean.java and DBHandler.java

**ProcessBean.java**:

```
package helpers;

import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class ProcessBean implements java.io.Serializable {
    public ProcessBean() {}

    public String processRequest(String option) {
     String query = "";
        String type = option.split("|")[0];
        int id = Integer.parseInt(option.split("|")[1]);

        if(type.equals("category"))
            query = "Select * from products where categoryId="+id;
        else if(type.equals("vendor"))
            query = "Select * from products where vendorId="+id;
        else
            query = "select * from products";

         Vector<String []> v = DBHandler.doQuery(query);
         return DBHandler.getQueryResultTable(v);
    }      
}
```

---

**DBHandler.java**:

```
package helpers;

import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DBHandler implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static Vector<String []> doQuery(String s) {
        String user = "xxx";
        String password = "xxx";
        String database = "xxx";
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://opatija:3306/" + database +
            "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password;      
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Vector<String[]> v = new Vector<String[]>();        

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s);

            ResultSetMetaData md = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int numCols = md.getColumnCount();

            while(resultSet.next()) {
                String [] tmp = new String[numCols];
                for(int i=0; i < numCols; i++)
                    tmp[i] = resultSet.getString(i+1);  // resultSet getString is 1 based
                v.add(tmp);                
                    }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        finally {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();                
                connection.close();
                }
            catch(SQLException e) {}  // don't do anything if the connection is not open.
        }
        return v;
    }  
    public static int doUpdate(String s) {
        String user = "xxx";
        String password = "xxx";
        String database = "xxx";
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://opatija:3306/" + database +
            "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password;      
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        int result = -1;   

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        statement = connection.createStatement();  
            result = statement.executeUpdate(s);
            }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        finally {
            try {
                statement.close();                
                connection.close();
                }
            catch(SQLException e) {}  // don't do anything if the connection is not open.
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getQueryResultTable(Vector<String []> v) {
        StringBuffer toReturn = new StringBuffer();
    toReturn.append("<table>");
    for(int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        String [] tmp = v.elementAt(i);
        toReturn.append("<tr>");        
        for(int j=0; j < tmp.length; j++)
            toReturn.append("<td>" + tmp[j] + "</td>");
        toReturn.append("</tr>");
        }
    toReturn.append("</table>"); 
    return toReturn.toString();
    }                       
}
```

When I am compiling ProcessBean, I get this error

```
ProcessBean.java:21: error: cannot find symbol  
Vector<String []> v = DBHandler.doQuery(query);  
                               ^   
symbol:   variable DBHandler   location: class ProcessBean  
ProcessBean.java:22: error: cannot find symbol  
return DBHandler.getQueryResultTable(v);  
                ^   
symbol:   variable DBHandler   location: class ProcessBean  
2 errors
```

I use `notepad++`, `mac` and `xQuartz` to connect to server, cd all the way to folder 'helpers' and then command -

```
javac ProcessBean.java
```

both the files are under folder helpers on server, `DBHandler` is successfully compiled.
Tried everything, but I can not figure it out.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're not using Vectors properly, or you're not importing the right one. Either way the problem is with your vector.

Comment: Oh nope never mind, sorry your error message is really unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I use notepad++, mac and xQuartz to connect to server, cd all the way to folder 'helpers' and then command - javac ProcessBean.java*

Be in parent folder of `helpers` and use the following compile command.

```
javac -d . helpers/ProcessBean.java
```

All the generated class files will be saved in their package specific folder.
Before this, make sure that the class path is also set to current folder that is

```
classpath = %classpath%;.
```

This will remove specific class not error within the package structure.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, that helped but I have one more question, I am trying to figure out how to send request.getParameter("option") to ProcessBean inside jsp                                                                         <jsp:useBean id="processBean" scope="session" class="helpers.ProcessBean" />
     ${processBean.processRequest('here')}

Comment: It should be `processBean.processRequest( request.getParameter( "option" ) )`.

Comment: Example @ [*JSP:useBean*](http://www.coderanch.com/t/473342/JSP/java/jsp-useBean)

Comment: please see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889660/send-parameter-from-jsp-to-servlet-using-jspusebean

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler to find DBHandler, it has to be on the classpath that the compiler is using.

You have edited your post to indicate that you compile on a command line, so you have a "default directory" (the one you cd to).  Let's say that directory is "projects", so it contains the directory "packages".

you would need to have the directory "projects" on the classpath.  You could do that by having your default directory for a command line compile in projects and having the classpath include "."; you could just have the "projects" directory in the classpath.

I don't know how to set system variables on a mac.  You can set a classpath on the command line by executing the command as: `javac -cp . helpers/ProcessBean.java`

It is possible that "." is on the classpath by default; I don't know about that on a mac either.

Comment: I don't think OP is experiencing classpath problems

Comment: sorry, that confused me, I use notepad++, I'm new to java

Comment: So how do you compile?  Are you on windows, unix, mac?  do you use a command line?  try to imagine that we don't know anything about what you're doing and ask your question that way; don't assume we can figure out what your question is without context information.

Comment: I use mac and xQuartz to connect to server, cd all the way to folder 'helpers' and then javac ProcessBean.java

Comment: @user3331487 Use an IDE and a build system such as Maven or Gradle to save yourself days of this sort of headaches.

Comment: You are going to need to understand classpaths -- cd to the folder that *contains* helpers, then javac helpers/ProcessBean.java.  Classpath will need to include "." in that case.  The compiler is looking for "helpers/DBHandler", and the only thing you have if your current directory is "helpers" is "DBHandler".  Compiling ProcessBean will also compile DBHandler if it is uncompiled, or if its source is more recent that its class file.

Comment: @user3331487 look at my answer to know how to comply efficiently