# send parameter from jsp to servlet using jsp:useBean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, usebean

I am beginner in java and trying to figure out how to send parameter from jsp to servlet using this

inside my jsp -

```
<%! String option;%>
<% option = request.getParameter("option"); %>
<jsp:useBean id="processBean" scope="session" class="helpers.ProcessBean" />
${processBean.processRequest(option)}
```

I want to send 'option' to processRequest but this way it is always empty string, so I am doing something wrong.Could not find anything online.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which one is empty? `option` or the return string of the `process` method?

Comment: I did System.out.println(option) inside processRequest and it is printing empty string

Comment: Then it must empty in `jsp` page. In Jsp page, check if `request.getParameter("option")` is empty. If yes, fix the page from where this query param is coming to this jsp page.

Comment: I tried that too in jsp it's not empty <h2><%= option%></h2>

Comment: You're going backwards.  You should be reading `request.getParameter("option")` in a Servlet, processing, then setting a request attribute for the output and forwarding to a JSP that prints that output.  You don't ever read request parameters in a JSP and invoke a servlet via a scriptlet call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable declared/set on the page's scripting language is not automatically available from EL. You can manually make it available via:

```
<c:set var="option" value="<%= option %>" />
```

before using it in EL.